# Empty C++11 initialiser list results in container with one default constructed object

Tags: c++11

The code below uses an empty C+11 style initialiser. When run the result is a `std::vector` containing one item, which appears to have been default constructed.

This is clearly an artificial case, and there are better ways of constructing an empty vector.  Nonetheles, the behaviour is counter-intuitive.  Is this a compiler/c++ runtime library bug?

I suspect one of `std::vector`'s other constructors is actually getting called here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> Container;

    Container c{{}};

    std::cout << "Vector size is: " << c.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto item: c)
    {
        std::cout << "Item: " << item.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Vector size is: 1
Item: 0x0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Compiler:

```
$ clang  --version
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
```

Comment: `Container c{{}};` constructs a vector with one element `{}` (default constructor of `std::shared`).

Comment: I think in this case, the vector is just initialize with a list of exactly one, default constructed element `{{}}`. What you want is, an empty list `{}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Container c;` is an empty container or `Container c{};`

`Container c{{}};` constructs the container with a default-constructed `std::shared_ptr<int>`

`Container c{{},{}};` constructs 2 `shared_ptr`s

Comment: This makes me want to create a type that takes peano integers on construction.  `{{{{}},{}},{{}},{}}`

Answer (score 3):

The initializer list is not empty instead of Container c{{}}; use Container c({});  // to pass an initializer list. Container c{} will be default initialized.